# Thinkster postman tutorial post request for login

Tags: http-post, postman

```
https://thinkster.io/tutorials/testing-backend-apis-with-postman/customizing-requests-in-postman
```

I am implementing a tutorial on thinkster for learning postman. They have a test site to run their request on, and it has following url to test the login feature:

```
https://conduit.productionready.io/api/users/login
```

I am under the section "Put your account credentials into the body of the POST request". I have already created an account on the test site and I can properly login from the site itself. But when I send the request via postman with the following body in raw mode:

```
{"user":{"email":"example@fake.com", "password":"nopassword"}}
```

I get the following response in pretty mode:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "email or password": [
      "is invalid"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or if they are getting a proper response from this site?

Comment: Can't check your syntax, as you are using the dummy request.
I tried and it failed; checked my password and it was wrong. Tried again with correct password, and it worked.

Comment: You can signup on their site and then use that to send request. But I changed the request json anyways to what I am using and getting the error. Try the new one please.

Comment: I did sign up and test and it did work for me. You are meant to chouse "raw" and "JSON", so that should be correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was missing the "JSON" parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case someone else needs the solution for this one.

> In the Body tab of the request editor, select the `raw` option, and then select `JSON` in the dropdown that appears to the right of the options.